# Tabs in post with unique link and title tags

Tags: wordpress, url, tabs, title, posts

I would like to be able to ad tabs to posts in Wordpress.

When the tab is clicked the url should change to postname/tabname and have title and description tags of its own.

So:

- A user clicks a tab in a post
- Url changes to postname/tabname
- Content outside tab box stays the same
- Title and description tags should change to something specified

It is supposed to look like the tabs on [this example](http://wpeden.com/product/frontend-post-and-media-manager/more-images/), except for the title tags.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? Please post some of your code.

Comment: I tried using tab plugins, but these are all jQuery based so the tabs are not accessible trough an url...

Comment: It's the same post, how would it have different URLs? Ain't you looking for URL hashtags?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by url hastags. Do you main an html anchor?